# Get height of element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm searching for a method to set the height of some sections to 100vh if the normal height of the section (the height defined by the content) is smaller than the viewport height.

For this reason I use the following code:

```
$(function() {

  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();

  $('section').each(function (index, value) {

    console.log($(this).attr('id') + ': ' + $(this).outerHeight());

    if ( windowWidth > windowHeight && windowHeight > $(this).outerHeight()) {
      $(this).addClass("total");
    }

    else {
      $(this).removeClass("total");
    }

  });

});
```

The console log says that one of my sections has a height of 880 px while it has 906 px in real. For this reason, the class is added, even if the display is too small which results in an awful design...

I think that I know why the height is returned, but I have no idea on how to get it right...

The section we are talking of contains circle progress bars which are animated by [this](http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/) plugin.
So you could say, that the circles aren't loaded yet, but they are! I once defined the function before defining the circles, and then the height in the console log was exactly the amount of the height of the circles smaller than it is now. So the difference of 26 px has to be caused by something else.

If I enter `$('#sectionID').outerHeight()` in the browsers console, the correct height is being returned, so it seems, that some element hasn't loaded when the for each function runs. But the function is inside the document ready function, so this shouldn't be the case...

Has anyone an idea?

---

**Code of the Circle**

```
var size = "130";

var progress1 = $('.progress1'),
    inited_progress1 = false;

progress1.circleProgress({
  value: 0,
  size: size,
  lineCap: "round",
  fill: {
    gradient: ["#00C853", "#00E676"]
  }
});

progress1.appear(
  { force_process: true }
);

progress1.on('appear', function() {
  if (!inited_progress1) {
    designer.circleProgress({
      value: 0.65,
      size: size,
      lineCap: "round",
      fill: {
        gradient: ["#7CB342", "#689F38"]
      }
    });

    inited_progress1 = true;
  }
});
```

There are eight of them. And on normal screens they are displayed in two rows.

---

#### Resolved

Thanks to an idea by [*zsawaf*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1929438/zsawaf) I could resolve the problem without using JavaScript.

Here's the SCSS/CSS code:

```
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  section {
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the plugin does some resizing after successful drawing. Have you tried attaching the test output to the plugin's `circle-animation-end` event instead of `document.ready`?

Comment: I can't do that because I animate the circles when the user scrolls to them. Otherwise, the animation would be completed by the time the user sees the circle. I'll post the code of one circle into the question.

Comment: Well, you could still add a debut output to the `start` and `stop` event, just to check if the plugin itself does any resizing, that you would have to manually pre-calculate. Even if the circle size itself is not the problem, as you stated, it could still be, that the plugin adds a padding before/after rendering the circles or similar

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why don't you set a min-height: 100vh to your sections while leaving height to be 100%? Then you wouldn't need javascript at all

Comment: @zsawaf I didn't do it this way, because I only wanted it to have the 100vh on landscape devices. On an iPad Pro for example it'll look very odd if you turn the iPad in portrait mode and a line of content floats in the middle of this huge screen. But, I could simply combine both methods and set the min-height of 100vh only if the windowWidth is greater than the windowHeight... Thanks for this idea!

Comment: @Sam94 are you familiar with media queries? You can target css for landscape and portrait views. Just set min-height 100vh to sections under the landscape media query, then remove min-height under portrait, or whatever it is you want to do. When you feel like you're trying to hack something with javascript and it feels unnatural, chances are you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh, that's even better. I didn't know that this was possible... I always thought, that media queries only work with pixels. Thank you very very much.